Why do I get an Inconsistency between the set N and Cantor's diagonal argument?
I would like to point to an inconsistency I found between the set of the Natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ being an infinite set of finite numbers and Cantor's diagonal argument.
Let’s create an ordered list of $\mathbb{N}$ in Base 1 from left to right




column
1
2
3
4
...










row














1

1












2

1
1











3

1
1
1










4

1
1
1
1









...















Because each consecutive number in the list is the previous number plus an additional ‘1’ in the next cell to the right then we know that all the cells in the diagonal have ‘1’ in them.
In Base 1 a number is greater than a group of numbers if there is at least one position(column) where the number has a ‘1’ in that position and all the numbers from the group don't.
Following a similar approach to Cantor's diagonal argument, we can construct the following sequence:  $b = b(1)b(2)b(3)...$    where $b(n)$ is the content of the cell in row $n$ and column $n$. In other words we construct a sequence from the diagonal of our list taking the content from one cell of each number in the list and putting it into the same position in the sequence as the number was taken from.
From Cantor's diagonal argument we know that this sequence is infinite and in our particular case an infinite sequence of ones. $b = 1111…$
So in Base 1 the sequence $b$ would represent a number that is equal to infinity which means that $b$ can't be a part of $\mathbb{N}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ is a set of finite numbers and for every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$,   $b = \infty > n$.
But for $b$ to be greater than all Natural numbers $b$ must have at least one position where it has ‘1’ and all Natural numbers don't, which is impossible because each position in $b$ is filled from the same position of some natural number from the list. So if $b$ is not greater than all Natural numbers and it can't be smaller then it must be equal to at least one of them which means it must be part of $\mathbb{N}$. We've reached the contradiction that points to an inconsistency.
This inconsistency means that either Cantor's diagonal argument is false and we can't use it to prove among other things that $|\mathbb{N}| < |\mathbb{R}|$, or that the statement about the Natural numbers as being an infinite set of finite numbers excluding infinity is the source of the inconsistency and that numbers with infinite integer parts like $b = 1111…$ shouldn't be excluded.
So let's say we've included the number $b$ in our list as the upper boundary. Let's call $a$ the number in the middle of the list. Then $a = b/2$, and there are $b/2$ numbers between $a$ and $b$ in the list. Since $b = \infty$ then $a = b/2 = \infty$ which means that there would be infinitely many infinite numbers in the list. And in that case we can make the following statement:
If numbers with infinite integer part are part of $\mathbb{N}$ then $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{R}|$
Proof : Every $x$ from $(0,1)$ we can put in one-to-one correspondence with its mirror image in relation to the decimal point excluding the point and the $0$ in front of it.
$$\mathbb{N}  <->  (0,1)$$
$$…8413       <->  0.3148…$$
$$57       <->  0.75$$
$$…16241       <->  0.14261…$$
We’ve shown a one-to-one correspondence in the case where numbers with infinite integer part are part of $\mathbb{N}$ which in that case would mean that $|\mathbb{N}| = |(0,1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$ or $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{R}|$,
and as a Consequence of that equality Cantor's diagonal argument stops being useful.

You would get more sympathy if you wrote "I know I must be wrong, but can somebody please point out my mistake?"

@TonyK True, although actually working through the errors will be a long slog.

One mistake seems to be "But for
to be greater than all Natural numbers
must have at least one position where it has ‘1’ and all Natural numbers don't"

There are a lot of misconceptions in your post, but I will deal with one of the early ones where you say "But for $b$ to be greater than all Natural numbers $b$ must have at least one position where it has ‘1’ and all Natural numbers don't, which is impossible because each position in $b$ is filled from the same position of some natural number from the list."
The problem is that you have observed a property that is true within one set, and assumed that it must also hold outside the set. You've also discovered that something can be true for an infinite collection of finite objects, but fail when you try to extend it to an infinite object.
There are some things we can say, for example:

There is an exact mapping between the natural numbers $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and the set of finite unary expansions $\{1, 11, 111, \ldots\}$.

For any two natural numbers $a$ and $b$, $b > a$ if and only if there is a position in $b$'s unary expansion that contains a 1 where $a$'s does not.

Further, for a natural number $b$ and a set of natural numbers $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$, if $b$ is larger than every element of $A$ then it has a 1 in its unary expansion that no element of $A$ has.

The infinite unary expansion $111\ldots$ does not correspond to any natural number.


It turns out that you can create a set $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ and you can give this new element the infinite unary expansion so $\infty = 111\ldots$, and in saying that $\infty > a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$ property 2 still holds in this new set (i.e. a bigger number has a 1 where a smaller number does not), but property 3 does not. And this is fine.

Thank you very much for this thorough and informative reply. But what if I change my argumentation after constructing $b = 111...$ to this: The number $b$ has a $b$ amount of '1' characters in its unary expension so there must be a number $c$ from $\mathbb{N}$ that contributed '1' from its $c(b)$ position to $b(b)$ position, which means $c$ has $b$ '1' in its unary expansion and consequently $c$ is infinite. And we get a contradicion. I suppose there's still a mistake, can you point me to it as well?

Or in other words where do the '1' in infinite positions/position of $b$ came from?

Also looking at the list from a geometric point of view we see that every consecutive sublist of the list forms an Isosceles Right Triangle, we also know that the whole list has a leg that is infinite (|$\mathbb{N}$|) and hypotenuse that is infinite ($b$). Is it possible that the other leg is not infinite?

It's really not clear what you're trying to say, and it is not the policy on this site for a question to become a back-and-forth discussion. I think you need to be clear on what you think your proof is trying to achieve, and how it achieves it, and then maybe consider asking a new question to understand where it fails.

Hi, I've asked a new question on the subject. You've been very helpful in this thread so i wanted to ask you if you could be so kind to help me find my mistake in my new argumentation. It's a lot shorter

That is not the diagonal argument. The diagonal argument takes the diagonal numbers and flips them. In your case, you didn't really flip anything, so that is not the diagonal argument you are using.
About your argument,

From Cantor's diagonal argument we know that this sequence is infinite and in our particular case an infinite sequence of ones. $b=1111\dots$

That is it. $b$ is not in $\Bbb N$. There cannot be any arguments to justify $b\in\Bbb N$. Anything in $\Bbb N$ has finitely many $1$s in its unary expansion.

So if $b$ is not greater than all Natural numbers and it can't be smaller then it must be equal to at least one of them which means it must be part of $\Bbb N$.

This is in general wrong. If you have a set $A$ and an element $c$ such that $c$ is not bigger than everything in $A$, and not smaller than everything in $A$ either, then $c$ does not have to be in $A$. You can take, say $A=\Bbb N$ and $c=\pi$.
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks for the reply. My main question now is since $b$ has $b$ characters '1' in its sequence then where did $b$ get its '1' in position $b(b)$, cause there can not be a natural number that contributed from position $b$ since $b = \infty$

@IgorZimbler: $b$ does not exist. It makes no sense whatsoever to talk about $b(b)$ or anything like that. The number $111\dots$ does not exist.
